# Creating network simulation / temporal models for videos?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, tracking, spatio-temporal-data, simulation

I know of ArcGIS Tracking analyst and QGIS Time Manager. I have a transportation network with time based schedule for buses. I will create time aware shapefiles from this data. Is it possible to create a simulation that shows buses moving along a track (as per the time ) using some plugin? This is necessary as i want to convert it to a video.

Essentially can you all list **all Add-ins / Plugins that deal with time based data** in popular GISystems.

Answer (score 4):

In ArcGIS 10 you can enable time on a layer (with the proper time fields) in the Time tab of the layer properties. Then using the Animation toolbar you can save to an animation file. See the help links for more details:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_enabling_time_on_data/005z0000000p000000/
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_time_animation/000900000067000000/

Comment: Yes indeed but i think without many proprietary extension like tracking server the full capabilities of ArcGIS are difficult to realize

Answer (score 2):

[Map Channels](http://www.mapchannels.com/) has an interesting [Animated Route Maps](http://www.mapchannels.com/RouteMaps.aspx) tool and API that you can embed directly on a web page and display simulated route animations.